# struts 1.3 - <html:radio> preselect

Tags: jsp, struts

I have been making an application using struts 1.3 and stuck in a very trivial problem. Within the login form, there are two radio buttons to chose from, for login as "test" and "admin". The code is as follows

```html
...          
<div class="radioLabel" >Test </div> 
<div class="radioButton" ><html:radio property="usertype" value="test" ></html:radio></div>

<div class="radioLabel" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Admin</div> 
<div class="radioButton" ><html:radio property="usertype" value="admin" ></html:radio></div>
...
```

While going through some posts, I found that setting the "initial" attribute of form-property tag which corresponds to the radio button would work. But it didn't work in my case.

```html
<form-bean name="LoginForm" type="company.project.model.LoginForm">
    ...  
    <form-property name="usertype" type="java.lang.String" initial="test" ></form-property>
</form-bean>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What you have posted here looks ok. Do the radio buttons work as expected except for this 'initial' issue?

Comment: Yes Martin, They do work properly. By proper working, I mean that at every page refresh there are 2 unselected radio buttons, and any one of them can be selected at a time. What I am looking for is to have one of the two buttons preselected on every page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, radio buttons **don't work properly** in Struts 1.x

You can verify this changing the radio buttons for a combobox, and you will see how all works perfect.

If you don't want to be stuck on that problem, try to emulate the desired behavior with javascript is a good alternative

Regards

Comment: Would be good to know what you mean by "radio buttons doesn't [sic] work properly"

Comment: Sorry for the grammar error. On topic, I had some problems using radio buttons in Struts 1.2. Let me find an example to publish here.

Comment: Thanks dcasanueva. I've used them successfully in the past so it would be good to know the specific issues you found.